# Entity Framework Skip/Take is very slow when number to skip is big

Tags: sql, performance, entity-framework, linq

So, code is very simple:

```
var result = dbContext.Skip(x).Take(y).ToList();
```

When x is big (~1.000.000), query is very slow. y is small - 10, 20.

SQL code for this is: (from sql profiler)

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY ...
OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY
```

The question is if anybody knows how to speed up such paging?

Comment: What happens when you do an order by before the Skip on a column which has index ?

Comment: What do you need 1 mill rows for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `OFFSET` .. `FETCH` is very useful when browsing the first pages from your large data (which is happening very often in most applications) and have a performance drawback when querying high order pages from large data.

Check this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190925145935/http://www.mssqlgirl.com/paging-function-performance-in-sql-server-2012.html) for more details regarding performance and alternatives to `OFFSET` .. `FETCH`.

Try to apply as many filters to your data before applying paging, so that paging is run against a smaller data volume. It is hard to imagine that the user wants no navigate through 1M rows.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this article, it really helps. Of course, resulting data set should be much smaller, because it doesn't make any sense to navigate through all of these records. Just found this issue and was wondering, why it happens.

Answer (score 8):

You are right on that, Skip().Take() approach is slow on SQL server. When I noticed that I used another approach and it worked good. Instead of using Linq Skip().Take() - which writes the code you showed - , I explicitly write the SQL as:

```
select top NTake ... from ... order by ... where orderedByValue > lastRetrievedValue
```

this one works fast (considering I have index on the ordered by column(s)).

Comment: This is a very nice workaround. I will make some benchmarks with it. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice idea. But at first time lastRetrievedValue will be zero

Comment: But there is some issue. Suppose there is a column which may have same values. that time orderedByValue > lastRetrievedValue will take from next greater value not from where it ended last time

Comment: You can then get top N with ties.

Comment: This proved to be much faster than using OFFSET FETCH on my one-off script that required paging through a large table.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Navigating though a million records in a database will always be slow in comparison to other ways, the database has to "skip" a million records, it does this by creating the result in memory and then discarding the first million rows.

Have you thought about a non-sql alternative (solr, lucene, etc), at least to get the ids of your rows first and then using a where id in () query?

Alternatively you could have a Search table (cooked up table) of your main table with only the bare minimum data and the Ids, so you can skip over that and get the ids and query the big table with those.

Comment: It doesn't work like that if you have an index and is fast.

Comment: @CetinBasoz it does work like that if you have conditions that are outside of the index scope, witch will happen in a lot of cases

Comment: You would never have conditions that are all outside of all indexes scopes and if there is a condition like that you'd create an index.

Answer (score 2):

You may lack some index on your table (or you may have too many of them), causing the SQL ordering/filtering to be unable to efficiently skip that many rows (or in case of too many indexes, causing it to fail choosing a good index for the job).

Try testing the SQL query directly:

- check its actual execution plan,
- check for missing index hints (may require to rewrite the query as a non-dynamic sql query, if ef has issued some dynamic query code),
- check for sorts spilling in temp db,
- ...

So, in short, check whether the issue is really an Entity-Framework issue or a 'pure' SQL issue.

Side note: EF issues `offset/fetch` paged queries only if it is configured for SQL2012 dialect. For previous dialects, it uses `row_number()`  instead.

Comment: From the [article](http://www.mssqlgirl.com/paging-function-performance-in-sql-server-2012.html) of @Alexei, it appears `row_number()` may perform a lot better than `OFFSET` - `FETCH` in your case. So you may also try to downgrade EF dialect to `SQL 2008` to check this. This would not be a nice hack though, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when EF CORE is converted to RawQuery, the Take/Skip value is parameterized, which will cause slowness, which can be solved by using the view

Comment: *which will cause slowness* -- Do you have any backing for your statement?

Comment: Isn't the View will have the same problem when you need to skip millions of rows?