# LINQ to Entities - Skip and Take very slow

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am writing a replacement system which deals with a large number of images. I've migrated what are deemed to be "live" images to a new database, but there is a requirement to search the old database through the UI to allow users to pull different images across.

I've put a view in my database which queries the old database so that I can expose it through Entity Framework. The view works well, and despite having several million records I get results pretty snappily.

My problem is when I try to run a query using LINQ to Entities. My search is paged, and limits results to 100 per page.

I have an IQueryable which I use to filter results, but for Skip/Take I have to add an order by. Example below shows getting page 2 of results (Skip 100, Take 100).

```
        if (firstId.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(x => x.Id >= firstId.Value);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupCode))
            query = query.Where(x => x.GroupCode == groupCode);

        var daResults = query
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
            .Skip(100)
            .Take(100)
            .ToList();
```

The SQL this generates is:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[FolderPath] AS [FolderPath], 
    [Project1].[Filename] AS [Filename], 
    [Project1].[IsFlagged] AS [IsFlagged], 
    [Project1].[IsHidden] AS [IsHidden], 
    [Project1].[TextField1] AS [TextField1], 
    [Project1].[TextField2] AS [TextField2], 
    [Project1].[TextField3] AS [TextField3], 
    [Project1].[TextField4] AS [TextField4], 
    [Project1].[GroupCode] AS [GroupCode], 
    [Project1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
    [Project1].[Created] AS [Created], 
    [Project1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Project1].[Updated] AS [Updated], 
    [Project1].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[FolderPath] AS [FolderPath], 
        [Extent1].[Filename] AS [Filename], 
        [Extent1].[IsFlagged] AS [IsFlagged], 
        [Extent1].[IsHidden] AS [IsHidden], 
        [Extent1].[TextField1] AS [TextField1], 
        [Extent1].[TextField2] AS [TextField2], 
        [Extent1].[TextField3] AS [TextField3], 
        [Extent1].[TextField4] AS [TextField4], 
        [Extent1].[GroupCode] AS [GroupCode], 
        [Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
        [Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
        [Extent1].[Updated] AS [Updated], 
        [Extent1].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy]
        FROM [dbo].[view_ProEditBulkImageInfo] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE
            ([Extent1].[Deleted] IS NULL) 
        AND ([Extent1].[Id] >= 300000)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC)
    OFFSET 100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

The issue seems to be that the first projection is fully evaluated (around 10 million records) which are then sorted before the top 100 rows are returned. The query execution plan shows the SORT cost as 92% of the batch.

This query takes around 30 seconds, just on the cusp of the timeout, so it's hit and miss as to whether it even returns.

I'm looking for some hints on how to speed this thing up, queries against the view are super quick (< 1 second).

Comment: Are you sure that you *need* to sort first before taking a page?

Comment: Linq should never be though off as more than syntactic sugar. Take and Skip are only slow because they're translated as OFFSET and FETCH, which are inherently slow on large sets of records. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531818/entity-framerowk-skip-take-is-very-slow-when-number-to-skip-is-big).

Comment: Is it required to navigate to arbitrary page, or navigation is in sequence (page 1, then 2, then 3...)?

Comment: LINQ won't let you Skip without an OrderBy.

Comment: And navigation is in sequence. The user will generally know the image Id, or at least the Id of an image that was from around the same time, so they are unlikely to page too far into the results.

Comment: If it's in sequence, you can replace skip-take with `Where(c => c.Id > lastIdFromLastPage).Take(100)` to get from one page to the next one.

Comment: I already have a comparison for the Id in the query because I want to return the first 100 results where the Id is equal to or above the search criteria. This always results in the OFFSET /  FETCH query in T-SQL which evaluates the whole inner query first and is agonisingly slow. See the link that @Kilazur posted above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531818/entity-framerowk-skip-take-is-very-slow-when-number-to-skip-is-big

Comment: Actually, that's a really interesting point. I'll have a look at that!

Comment: It looks like that the query isn't covered by an index, and it needs to sort the whole table by Id instead of just index scan. What are table indexes? Is Id column the clustered index of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to the end of writing this question, and then struck upon a slightly different approach. I thought I'd post anyway because it may be useful.

I've changed my code structure. I now do an extended .Take() first. This gets me all pages up to, and including, the page I want to return. Then I do the order by and skip to get only the page I want.

```
        query = query
            .Take((page.GetValueOrDefault(0) + 1) * recordCount.GetValueOrDefault(100));

        // Now skip to the required page. 
        daResults = daResults
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
            .Skip(page.GetValueOrDefault(0) * recordCount.GetValueOrDefault(100))
            .ToList();
```

The original Skip/Take results in the following SQL, which needs that internal query that was previously fully evaluated, and is slow:

```
ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC)
OFFSET 100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Changing it, that internal query is much smaller. That internal sub-query uses SELECT TOP(200), which is lightning fast, and then applies the OFFSET etc. to the reduced results

I'm still only enumerating results (.ToList()) after all this has happened, so it all stays in the database and the results are now pretty much instant again.

Comment: Hmm, so when the page is close to the last, you'll read million records in memory just to take the last 100?

Comment: Yes, although I've just tried without the first enumeration, and the query is all fully database side again. (Edits above)

Comment: if its working for you then please mark it as an answer