# Entity Framework SqlQuery : how to do implement .where .orderby extend and include navigation properties?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

How to do paging processing for this dynamic query in Entity Framework 6 ?

`BillDetailLogsDto` is a custom result DTO not an database entity,how to sqlquery include navigation properties and It is impossible to pass parameters without using SqlParameter How to implement sqlquery use `.Where` `.OrderBy` extend

```
using (ProjectDbContext context = new ProjectDbContext())
{
    var query = context.Database.SqlQuery<BillDetailLogsDto>("SELECT *, SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS QSAmount FROM BillDetailLogs").AsQueryable();
    var result = query.Select(t => new
            {
                CustomerName = t.Customer.Name,
                t.CustomerId,
                t.Type,
                t.SortId,
                t.Amount,
                QAmount=t.QSAmount,
                t.ObjDate,
                t.OpRemark,
                t.Remark,
                t.SendOrderId,
                CreatedUserName = t.CreatedUser.RealName,
                t.CreatedDate,
            }).OrderByDescending(t => t.SortId);

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: ToPagedList needs pageNumber and currentPage as parameters: `public static IPagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> superset, int pageNumber, int pageSize);` For navigation properties you might need to use `Include` method, e.g. `billDetailLogsDto.Include(x => x.Customer).Include("MoreStuff").Where(...)`

Comment: @beiduoan did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to your query:

```
.Skip(pageSize * page).Take(pageSize)
```

Comment: Just be mindful of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531818/entity-framerowk-skip-take-is-very-slow-when-number-to-skip-is-big