# C# Linq query execution order

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Consider the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<Owner> GetOwners(OwnerParameters ownerParameters)
{
    return FindAll()
        .OrderBy(on => on.Name)
        .Skip((ownerParameters.PageNumber - 1) * ownerParameters.PageSize)
        .Take(ownerParameters.PageSize)
        .ToList();
}
```

Where `FindAll()` is a repository pattern method that returns `IQueryable<Owner>`. Does having `.OrderBy()` before `.Skip()` and `.Take()` methods mean that all the elements from the `Owner` data table will be retrieved and ordered, or, does Linq take into account that `.Skip()` and `.Take()` methods might narrow down the required `Owner` elements and only after having retrieved those will the ordering happen?

EDIT: Profiler log:

```
SELECT XXX
FROM [Owners] AS [a]
ORDER BY [a].[Name]
OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY',N'@__p_0 int,@__p_1 int',@__p_0=0,@__p_1=10
```

Comment: To whomever voted to close this due to 'needs more details or clarity', what exactly do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All records wouldn't be retrieved. Depending on your backend a query would be generated, that orders by Name, skips N rows and takes next M rows. Only the query result is retrieved, triggered by .ToList().
ie: In MS SQL server the query might look like:

```
Select top(M) row_number() over (order by Name) as RowNo, * 
from myTable
where RowNo > N
```

That type of query is not very effective but that is another matter and you could create your custom workaround.

EDIT: I remembered MS SQL code generated wrong. It was:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY ...
OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY
```

That one is also slow. If you have speed consideration then write your own SQL and send with Linq. Basically what you do is to keep the lastRetrieved value and set it as a parameter:

```
select top(NTake) ... from ... 
order by ... 
where orderedByValue > @lastRetrievedValue
```

(You can send raw SQL queries in Linq)

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate on why exactly would it not be very effective?

Comment: @astralmaster, creating a row_number() ... then getting top (N) is a slow operation (not the TOP N but row_number() part is slow). If you have  large data and need to get many pages, this gets slow. A custom query instead, where you keep the last retrieved name client side and ask for Names greater than that one is much faster (assuming you have an index on Name). Actually there was a post about this and this custom query approach is much faster. If I can find that post, I will add the link.

Comment: So would you say, using Linq and Entity Framework will produce significantly slower query for this exact case, and would rather construct one yourself?

Comment: @astralmaster, yes. But fast, slow ... are relative to its users. What is slow for me, might be acceptable for you in a small data set (where a custom query gain would be negligible then). I still couldn't find that post :( - it was a post of mine though.

Comment: @astralmaster, I found it at last. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531818/entity-framework-skip-take-is-very-slow-when-number-to-skip-is-big/34533010#34533010

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately, this depends on what `FindAll()` does and what it returns:

- if it returns `IEnumerable<T>`, then it is using LINQ-to-Objects, which *mostly* just does literally what it is told; if you sort then pages, then *it* sorts then pages; if you page then sort, then *it* pages then sorts
- however, if it returns `IQueryable<T>`, then the query is being *composed* - and only actually executed in `ToList()`, at which point the provider model gets a chance to inspect your query tree and build the most suitable implementation possible, which often means: writing a SQL query that includes an `ORDER BY` and some paging hints suitable for the specific RDBMS; if your code paged then sort (which is... unusual) then I would *expect* most providers to *either* write some kind of horrible sub-query to try to describe that, *or* just throw an exception (perhaps `NotSupportedException`) in disgust

Comment: It is definitely `IQueryable<Owner>`. And RDBMS is SQL Server. So does that mean, not the entirety of the `Owner` table will be retrieved, but only the portion requested by `.Take()` and `.Skip()` and only ordered(sorted) afterwards?

Comment: @astralmaster I would absolutely expect that to issue a query that does the sorting and paging at the database server, only returning the relevant page; however! if unsure: use whatever profiling and monitoring tools are available

Comment: @MarcGravell: I don't agree with that it's "only ordered afterwards". The database needs to apply the ordering before it can use paging, otherwise the returned rows were arbitrary. So maybe i have misunderstood OP's comment or your answer or you've overlooked it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter oh, yeah, that was poorly interpreted / phrased by me; I said "yes" meaning "no" :) the words *after* the yes seem clear, though; I've removed the "yes" (the rest is unchanged)

Comment: In SQL server it would generate a code like: SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY ...
OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY which does the ordering on server side and fetching only needed rows, BUT that query is slow in MS SQL server. A custom query is much better.

Answer (score 0):

A quick example to demonstrate that order of query matters. The explanations given above are good.

```
var test1 = await _dbContext.UserActivityLogs
.Where(x => x.ExternalSyncLogId == request.Id)
.Skip(0).Take(25)
.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

This query transpile to

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[ActionType], [u].[ActivityEndTime], [u].[ActivityStartTime], [u].[ActivityType], [u].[Created], [u].[CreatedBy], [u].[EntityId], [u].[ExternalSyncLogId], [u].[LastModified], [u].[LastModifiedBy], [u].[RequestBody], [u].[ResponseBody], [u].[Source], [u].[TenantId]
FROM [UserActivityLogs] AS [u]
WHERE ([u].[ExternalSyncLogId] IS NULL
ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
OFFSET @__p_1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_2 ROWS ONLY',N'@__p_1 int,@__p_2 int',@__p_1=0,@__p_2=25
```

**Execution time: 29**

But if we just change the sequence then

```
var test2 = await _dbContext.UserActivityLogs
.Skip(0).Take(25)
.Where(x => x.ExternalSyncLogId == request.Id)
.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Translated as

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[ActionType], [t].[ActivityEndTime], [t].[ActivityStartTime], [t].[ActivityType], [t].[Created], [t].[CreatedBy], [t].[EntityId], [t].[ExternalSyncLogId], [t].[LastModified], [t].[LastModifiedBy], [t].[RequestBody], [t].[ResponseBody], [t].[Source], [t].[TenantId]
FROM (
    SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[ActionType], [u].[ActivityEndTime], [u].[ActivityStartTime], [u].[ActivityType], [u].[Created], [u].[CreatedBy], [u].[EntityId], [u].[ExternalSyncLogId], [u].[LastModified], [u].[LastModifiedBy], [u].[RequestBody], [u].[ResponseBody], [u].[Source], [u].[TenantId]
    FROM [UserActivityLogs] AS [u]
    ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
    OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
) AS [t]
WHERE [t].[ExternalSyncLogId] IS NULL',N'@__p_0 int,@__p_1 int',@__p_0=0,@__p_1=25
```

**Execution time: 474**